# What is the hook that needs to be triggered on Post Order created with WooCommerce REST-API?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I need the hook to trigger when an order is created via REST-API with WooCommerce.

The hooks I tried are below and none of them worked.

```
save_post_shop_order
woocommerce_api_create_order
woocommerce_new_order
woocommerce_thankyou
woocommerce_rest_prepare_shop_order_object
```

Answer (score 1):

`rest_insert_shop_order` Use this hook.

Fires after a single post is created or updated [via the REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_insert_this-post_type/).